# Bad htaccess rule - I dont known how to repair it

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/((\w{2})/)?[^/]+/d\-(\d+)/?$
RewriteRule (.*) /www/index.php?action=static&lang=$2&sp=0&detail=$3 [L,QSA]
```

I entry this URL: https://example.com/barvy-bisley-blf/d-30/, but on the output is: https://www.example/www/index.php?action=static&lang=&sp=0&detail=

How to edit this rule, to get this output? (add ID 30 to output).

https://www.example.com/www/index.php?action=static&lang=&sp=0&detail=30

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current rule only has a single capture group, that is why only `$1` is filled, not further capture variable. Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/((\w{2})/)?[^/]+/d\-(\d+)/?$
RewriteRule ^/?(:\w{2}/)?[^/]+/(d)\-(\d+)/?$ /www/index.php?action=static&lang=$2&sp=0&detail=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please note that we can only *guess* some of the details of your requirements, since your information is pretty vague and sparse...

The above rule will rewrite an incoming request

```
https://example.com/barvy-bisley-blf/d-30/
```

to the internal URL

```
https://www.example.com/www/index.php?action=static&lang=d&sp=0&detail=30
```

*if* interpretation of `.htaccess` style files is enabled, the rewriting module is loaded into the http server and the `.htaccess` style file is stored at the correct location.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: @mabezdek Maybe you could be a little more verbose and post the _exact and full_ error message as shown in the http servers error log file? Thanks!

Comment: The error  log is empty :( It's only show Error 500 (Internal Error)

Comment: That is not possible. If the http server raises an internal error, then it logs an error. _Unless_ you really messed up the logging in your configuration...

Comment: Cannot compile regular expression '^/?(?\w{2}/)?[^/]+/(d)\-(\d+)/?$'

Comment: That validator does not really help me without me knowing the domain, does it?

Comment: Validator returns an error `Cannot compile regular expression '^/?(?\w{2}/)?[^/]+/(d)\-(\d+)/?$'`

Comment: Ah, sorry, a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: This expression not working for me .. I fixed by this: `^\/?(\w{2}\/)?[^\/]+\/(d)\-(\d+)\/?$`, what do you mean about that? It's ok? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, everything that works as you need it is "ok" per definition ;-) Have fun!

Comment: Thank you, without you I would come to this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to add the action, sp and lang to the url as theses are not dynamic. inex.php?detail=30 would enough but i think this rewrite rule may work for you based on the information you provided.

Capture (\d+) into %1

And rewrite (redirect) into action=static&lang=&sp=0&detail=detail=%1

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} d\-=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?action=static&lang=&sp=0&detail=%1 [L,R=301]
```